# How to acess an array of hashes in a Perl module

Tags: perl, module

Here the Perl module `Information`.

```
package Information;

sub bar {
  print "Hello $_[0]\n";
}

sub new {
  my $class = shift;
  my $tax = sprintf("%.2f", rand);

  my $self = { value => $tax };

  bless $self, $class;
}

sub get_info {
  my $self  = shift;

  my $group = [
    {
      "id" => "111",
      "p"  => { "retail" => 1.37, "unit"   => 1.46 }
    },
    {
      "id" => "222",
      "p"  => { "retail" => 2.84, "unit"   => 2.24 }
    },
    {
      "id" => "333",
      "p"  => { "retail" => 3.24, "unit"   => 3.76 }
    }
  ];

  return $product_group;
}

1;
```

I have to write another file 'somethin.pl' in which I have to access all of the `$group` information. I have something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

use CGI; 
use CGI::Carp qw(warningsToBrowser fatalsToBrowser);

use warnings;

require './Information.pm';
Information::new();
my $return = Information::get_info();
```

How to access all the information in the `$group`?

Answer (score 0):

Your subroutine creates $group but returns $product_group, which is uninitialized.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you must change the last line of `get_info` to read

```
return $group;
```

as there is no `$product_group`.

It is far from clear what your module is supposed to do, as the data returned by `get_info` has nothing to do with the contents of `$self`.

Your module file is basically okay, but it *must* be in a file called `Information.pm` in one of the directories listed in `@INC`.

However, your main program is wrong. You are not using the object returned by the `new` constructor, and you shouldn't be calling the methods in the module by using their package name.

This is closer to what you need

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Information;

my $info = Information->new;

my $group = $info->get_info;
```

but that doesn't do much except set `$group` to the data structure returned by the `get_info` method, which is an invariant data structure.

If you explained a little more about what you wanted to do (in a new question) then I am sure we would be able to help you.